# Populate form from table select with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with data, how can I populate a form on the same page with the data when the edit button is clicked. Basically is should be the same as this example but without using knockoutjs

http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/2cr2f/

```
@model IEnumerable<GenomindApp2.Areas.RulesEngine.ViewModels.GeneViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index2";
}

<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GeneValue)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GeneCode)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GeneName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GeneComments)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WildType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WildTypeAllele)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AtRiskAllele)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GeneCode)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GeneName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GeneComments)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WildType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WildTypeAllele)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AtRiskAllele)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like that:

Model:

```
public class ModelB
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var model = new List<ModelB>
    {
        new ModelB{Age = 2, Name = "Bob"},
        new ModelB{Age = 7, Name = "Sam"},
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(List<ModelB> model)
{
    //whatever
}
```

View:

```
@model List<TestWebApplication.Models.ModelB>

...

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        Age: @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Age);
        Name: @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[i].Name);
        <br />
    }

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Please note that I used **for** instead of **foreach**. When you populate a form you shouldn't use foreach - it will not render well.

Comment: the foreach is just for the table data which contains an edit button..when the edit button is clicked i want the values in the form to be populated with the edit item. please the example here http://jsfiddle.net/jiggle/2cr2f/